# SF Symbol Not Showing on a button in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am very new at IOS dev, this is my day one. so I have been playing with SF symbols and tried to add it into a button, but somehow it doesn't appear at the button

[The Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq1VB.jpg)

The color should be black and it should've appear on the button.
Perhaps I made a beginner mistake, but still don't know ho two fix it. so what did I do wrong?

```
struct ButtonBig: View {
    var ButtonText:String
    var ButtonIcon:String
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
            .frame(width:117, height: 112.36, alignment:.center)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            VStack{
                Image(systemName: ButtonIcon).padding()
                Text(ButtonText).foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

```
Button(action: ) {
                        ButtonBig(ButtonText: "Button3",ButtonIcon: "calendar")
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add button style to `PlainButtonStyle()`

```
Button(action: ) {
    ButtonBig(ButtonText: "Button3",ButtonIcon: "calendar")
}.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) //<-- Here
```

Or you can set renderingMode mode to original.

```
// Other code
VStack{
    Image(systemName: ButtonIcon).renderingMode(.original).padding() //<--- Here
    Text(ButtonText).foregroundColor(.white)
}
// Other code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overlaying your button image and text on the `RoundedRectangle` shape view like below :

```
struct ButtonBig: View {

    var ButtonText:String
    var ButtonIcon:String

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                .frame(width:117, height: 112.36, alignment:.center)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .overlay(
                    VStack{
                        Image(systemName: ButtonIcon).renderingMode(.original).padding()
                        Text(ButtonText).foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                 )
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can also do it by just setting the button style directly to `HStack` of the button.

```
HStack {
       Button(action: {
       }, label: {
           ButtonBig(ButtonText: "Button1",ButtonIcon: "calendar")
       })
                
       Button(action: {
       }, label: {
           ButtonBig(ButtonText: "Button2",ButtonIcon: "calendar")
       })
                
       Button(action: {
       }, label: {
           ButtonBig(ButtonText: "Button3",ButtonIcon: "calendar")
       })

}.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) //Set the button style to HStack instead of each button
```